# Hosting multiple websites on the same IP address (different machines)

Tags: laravel, iis, xampp, web, reverse-proxy

So, my setup is:

Windows server - Already hosting a website in IIS (`web1.example1.com`)

Windows 10 PC - Want to host another website using Xampp (`web2.example2.com`)

I don't own either of these domain names, only the subdomains (not sure if this matters)

I have got this to work by setting up another site in IIS then using a reverse-proxy, however, I ran into a problem using this method. I'm using Laravel on my windows 10 PC, and I when try to access my resources it uses my internal IP rather than the domain name (therefore doesn't work externally). I can get around this by using `URL::forceRootUrl()` in my `routes/web.php` however then I can't redirect to other sites (need to use OAuth).

I have tried searching around for solutions that will let me use both of these, but I'm starting to think using a reverse-proxy just isn't going to work for what I want.